# Public variable access

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called `Global.cs`:

```
public class Global
{
    private string id= string.Empty;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id;}
        set { id= value; }
    }
}
```

Now in the `Main` class,

```
public class Main
{
    public Global objGlobal;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objGlobal= new Global();
        objGlobal.id="XX001";
    }
    public void Setdata()
    {
        // Trying to access objGlobal.id value here but it's null 
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That won't work.  What if two users access your site at once? Consider using session state.

Comment: Your field and your property are both called `id`? Does that even compile?

Comment: Are you calling `Setdata` before `Page_Load` is invoked?

Comment: Setdata() called from pageload..

Comment: @SLaks: That's not a problem at all. The data is not static, each page instance will have its own instance of the object.

Comment: The code `objGlobal.id="XX001";` would not compile. You can't access the private member of the class. What does your code actually look like?

Comment: @Guffa,Even if I make id as "public" it's not accessible.

Comment: @Rishi: The point is that you could not possibly get a null value, as the code would not even run. You have to show the actual code that you are using, it's no possible to find an error in the code that you are using by looking at code that you are not using.

Comment: @Guffa, It's big code to post :(

Comment: @Rishi: Then you need to post an example that shows the problem that you have. The code posted doesn't have the problem that you desribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you always be getting/setting "Id" rather than "id". As "id" is private.

Comment: Consider a scenario where I retrieve user profile info and save in variables on page load event.Now I need few of my functions to use those variables data without passing them as a function argument.Also, Don't want to use session.

Comment: Are these functions using the variables all in the same class?

Comment: Yes in the same class but in different function

Comment: If you plan on storing more than ID, which I assume you do, I would create a User class instead, give it Public ID, and whatever else you want, then in your Main class define List<User> userList = new List<User>(); Then when you need a new user create a new instance of User and do userList.Add(newUser). This will give you a List of Users that you can access from any method within your Main class. If you like i'll edit this answer and demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `XX` class instance is more than one time.

If you need to persist some user-retalive info, try storing it into the [SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you need to just have the static class with some static data, add the `static` keyword to both class and its members.

Comment: SO you mean to say without using "Session" and "Static" I can't preserve some variable through out the class?

Comment: @Rishi You cant persist it in the classes that you create inside each web request, because each time the request is performed, the classes will be recreated, losing all the references to old instances.